# Is it possible to add multiple Font style at the same time at some string text?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am trying to draw a string into an image.is it possible to add multiple Font style at the same text(bold and italic).?

my code is:

```
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 16);

        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(text, 100, 100);
        g.dispose();
```

but i  want to add italic with bold attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29), you can OR together the styles you want.

```
Font font = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16);
```